# haversine / spherical law of cosines / vincenty in sql query

Tags: distance, haversine, trigonometry

I'm testing out different formulas for finding specific points on the earth within a given radius from a given latitude/longitude. I've been using the 'spherical law of cosines' and what I believe to be an implementation of Haversine.

For the following formulas, these are the variables:

[$lat/$lon] = point of origin

[latitude/longitude] = second point

[$radius] = radius

Spherical law of cosines

```
3959 * acos( cos( radians('.$lat.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$lon.') ) + sin( radians('.$lat.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) <= '.$radius.';
```

Haversine (at least I think it is!)

```
3959*3.1415926*sqrt((latitude-'.$lat.')*(latitude-'.$lat.') + cos(latitude/57.29578)*cos('.$lat.'/57.29578)*(longitude-'.$lon.')*(longitude-'.$lon.'))/180) <= '.$radius.';';
```

I initially came across a lot of information saying that Haversine was the gold standard as far as accuracy. However, there also seems to be an opinion that the spherical law of cosines is more accurate than Haversine, as long as the distance being measured is greater than 5 metres or so. Furthermore, some say that Vincenty is said to trump both in accuracy.

Three questions:

Is my Haversine formula actually Haversine or it something else?

Any thoughts on which wins out for most accurate?

Can anyone provide me with a formulation for Vincenty along the lines of the above forumlas?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your so-called Haversine formula is totally incorrect.

Firstly it contains 7 left parentheses and 8 right parentheses.

Secondly conversion from degrees to radians is done in some cases by dividing by 57.29578 then there's a constant pi up the front and a constant 180 down the back.

Thirdly `haversine(x) = sin(x / 2) ** 2` and I don't see the `/ 2` anywhere.

Fourthly there should be an `asin` function call near the front.

Correct formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Answer (score -1):

My answer will be more Specific for your first and second answer

**Q1: Is my Haversine formula actually Haversine or it something else?**

I Don not understand  Your haversine  formula you made it
The write one or exactly the SQl query for haversine Formula is that
From Google Developer Site [Click Here For Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql)

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

This SQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate. It calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance value is less than 25, orders the whole query by distance, and limits it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.

You can make your Changes for this SQL query To be exactly What you want to.

**Q2: Any thoughts on which wins out for most accurate?**

There is no final answer for who can win?!, But we can deal with that:

1.Haversine is More Faster.

2.Spherical law of cosines is more accurate for Small distances.

And About Q3 I Know that the vincenty Formula is the most accurate But it is the slowest One

Comment: Q1: Your recommended formula starts off with `SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos(` ... the `acos` brands it as the spherical law of cosines formula, definitely not the haversine formula. Q2.1 haversine is NOT faster. Q2.2 spherical law of cosines is LESS accurate over small differences.